# calling route of Laravel project with Exec command

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've a project in Laravel 5, and I need to call a route of other project made in the same framework, I was thinkg in call this route using `exec` command of PHP, is possible to call a route?I've been callin PHP scripts and it works fine, but now I need to call a route an get the response. The reason of why I'm doing this of this way are a lot so I'll not explain it here or the post will get very long. Thank  you!

Comment: `exec` to call a route with HTTP? Why not using `file_get_contents` or something similar? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Hi @PeterPan666 yes, I'm open to sugerences. Yes, it seems to be a good choice, I said `exec` because I've installed Pthreads extension, and it only work in the CLI and non in browser

Comment: Don't know Pthreads but Laravel's route need an HTTP request to be resolved. If the other project is on the same server, you could add a command to artisan that do the same thing as the route and execute it with `exec` though.